# Python regex for one word

Tags: python, regex

I have this dataframe where I'm trying to delete all one word responses, with/without punctuation and could have spaces in front too. Most of the values are full, long sentences but please find below the kind I am trying to remove.

| column |
| --- |
| thanks |
| hello! |
| really.... |

My try
`textonly = re.sub('^.\w+\w+.$' , " " , df.column)`

error (even though dtype is string) : expected string or bytes-like object

Another try which seems to go through but doesnt change anything :/

`textonly = re.sub('^.\w+\w+.$' , " " , str(df.column))`

Please help identify what I'm missing

Comment: Use [df.column.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.str.replace) instead

Comment: `^[^\n ]*\n`(with multiline flag `m` set) matches lines with no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'^\W*\w+\W*$', '', regex=True)
```

If you mean *natural language words* by "words", i.e. only consisting of letters, you may use

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'^[\W\d_]*[^\W\d_]+[\W\d_]*$', '', regex=True)
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `[\W\d_]*` - zero or more non-word chars, digits and `_`
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more chars other than non-word chars, digits and `_`
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You could also `not` use regex and then check if the string has a space in it

```py
x = [
    'hej med dig',
    'hej',
]

print([x for x in x if ' ' in x.strip()])
```